# Typescript interface on mongoose populate

Tags: typescript, mongoose

So I have this mongoose model as below:

```
const userSchema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: String,
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,       
        phoneNumber: String,
        cmt: {
            type: String,
            ref: 'Cmt',
        },      
    },  
);
```

As you can see cmt field is pointing to another model called `Cmt` whose details I'll be getting used `populate`

now on another instance i need to pass  in the cmt id for linking it with the `userSchema`

but at that time i'll get a typescript error of `"Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ICmt'."`

`ICmt` being the interface definition of Cmt.

The userschema interface is given below.

```
export interface IUser {
    _id: string;
    email: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    cmt: ICmt;
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

How can I fix this error without messing both populate query and create query?

Answer (score 0):

This was an easy solution, wrong on my end.

You could use an `|` `(or)` statement on the interface, that will solve the problem for the tslint errors that may occur

So my user interface will become

```
export interface IUser {
    _id: string;
    email: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    cmt: ICmt | string;
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

So there won't be any more tslint errors or tsignore that I need to worry about

Answer (score 0):

The following will work, but will require type checking for either case.

```
export interface User {  // Issue when using I in declarations v.6++
  cmt: Cmt | mongoose.Types.ObjectID;
}
```

Comment: DMonde, if you think that this is a comment on an existing answer please delete it. If you think that this is an answer, pelase [edit] it according to [answer]. Please take the [tour] to understand why; and that might also clear up some of your misunderstanding on how Stackoverflow is meant to be used. The info should also help you with improving your posts (past and future), to increase the chance that they are perceived as helpful.

Comment: My post is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Then why do you say in the initial version that this is a comment?